# How do I pass a NSInputStream to MPMoviePlayerController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a video in the form of `NSInputStream` object that I'm using to write data to. I know `MPMoviePlayerController` can receive a file location with an `NSURL`, however what I'm wondering is whether it provides functionality for reading bytes from an `NSInputStream`, or how this could be achieved?

I've heard mentions about how `NSURLProtocol` can be used to set up a custom protocol to do this sort of thing, but I've not seen any samples with readable code.

Comment: is there any help with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fear this is not possible. The init method

```
- (id)initWithContentURL:(NSURL *)url
```

requires a *file* URL. So, we cannot be sure that MPMoviePlayerController will use the URL loading system. Very likely it's using the File Manager API.

The preferred API would be (anyway):

```
- (id)initWithStream:(NSInputStream*)inputStream;
```

I would suggest to file an enhancement request to Apple.